# How do immortals deal with a mortal cheating death?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, character-death

So D&D characters come back from the dead all the time during campaigns through use of magic, and no one really raises too much of a fuss about it. That's fine.

But if a character (and I'm more thinking of an NPC or a villain more than PC/good guys, if that matters) repeatedly extended their life through unnatural magic, wouldn't some immortal beings take notice of a soul that refused to move on? Would those beings be Gods (maybe with the grave domain), and if so, which ones and how would they deal with the situation?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 9):

## Kelemvor would be very annoyed with that.

It is very likely that *Doomguides*: the powerful clerics, paladins and other followers would visit transgressor very soon.

If he transformed into undead to cheat death, you can bet *Knights of the Eternal Order* (or some adventures) would come knocking on his doors too.

## Inevitables might have something to say too

In 3.5 [Maruts](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/inevitable.htm) were Inevitables who seeks and destroys anyone who unnaturally extends their lifespan. In 5e *Mordekainen Tome of Foes* they returned to their original role in 1e (and 4e) as cosmic enforcers, now answering to Primus: leader of modrons and ruler of Mechanus. In this edition only contract-enforcing Kolyarut (which is now a single entity) is mentioned directly, but it is said that other Inevitables exist, so it is quite possibly that there still is some entity which seeks those who cheats death and sends Maruts for them.

Comment: It might be worth noting that FR canon has several high-profile liches who have been kicking about for quite some time - see for instance [Szass Tam](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Szass_Tam) (effective ruler of Thay) and [Larloch](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Larloch) (who has spent nearly 2000 years as a lich!) Such individuals are certainly not in Kelemvor's good books, but may well be beyond the reach of his mortal followers and even his divine servants.

Comment: @Carcer Not to mention the Undying Court